# Dynamically (out of for loop) populate a dataframe with another dataframe with n-rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have certain data in a list extracted from a bayesian processing from certain electrodes and I want to populate a dataframe out of a loop. First I have a list of 729 processing outcomes and an object `elecs` which is basically a list of 729 pairs of electrodes (27*27) as you can see.

```
> head(elecs)
  X Elec1 Elec2
1 1     1     1
2 2     1     2
3 3     1     3
4 4     1     4
5 5     1     5
6 6     1     6
```

The thing is I would like to fill `dataf1` with the outcome of this loop which happens to be a dataframe of 4000 rows.

```
dataf1 <- data.frame('Elec1'=rep(NA,4000*729),'Elec2'=rep(NA,4000*729),'int'=rep(NA,4000*729))

for (i in nrow(elecs)){
  Elec1=as.data.frame(rep(elecs[i,]$Elec1,4000))
  Elec2=as.data.frame(rep(elecs[i,]$Elec2,4000))
  post <- posterior_samples(bayeslist[[i]])
  int <- as.data.frame(post$b_Intercept)
  df <- cbind(Elec1,Elec2,est)
  colnames(df) <- c('Elec1','Elec2','int')
  
  dataf1[(1+(i-1)*4000):((1+(i-1)*4000)+3999),c('Elec1','Elec2','int')] <- df

}
```

Everything works perfectly fine until the last line in the loop:

`dataf1[(1+(i-1)*4000):((1+(i-1)*4000)+3999),c('Elec1','Elec2','int')] <- df`

And I don't know why exactly this is not working as expected and populating the `dataf1` preinitialised dataframe.

Any insight, as always, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a nasty typo in your last line, i.e. you're missing a closing bracket! Instead of `dataf1[(1+(i-1)*4000):((1+(i-1)*4000)+3999),c('Elec1','Elec2','int'] <- df` you should have `dataf1[(1+(i-1)*4000):((1+(i-1)*4000)+3999),c('Elec1','Elec2','int')] <- df`. But I am not sure this is the only mistake.

Comment: You are right, but no, this is not the mistake, I had it fixed and still it was not populating it. Thanks though, I am editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was missing the init in the for, so it's kinda newbie typo. Apart from this, the code works, in case anyone is wondering.

`for (i in nrow(elecs)){`
`for (i in 1:nrow(elecs)){`